# HTML5 <section> with asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, html

I am rewriting some of my asp.net MVC projects into html5, and I am getting confused about the `<section>` element. When should I use it? The `<header>` and `<footer>` elements makes sence ofcourse, but I dont really know when to use `<section>`. Before I used a main div to wrap all the partial views to a MasterView.

Wouldnt `<section>` fit for showing the partial views of a MasterView? I have read some about section and It seems like it should consist of a header and a footer which will be quite tending for a partial view?

The structure for the MasterView would be:

---`<header>`

------ `<nav>`

---`<section>`

------- here goes partial views with their own divs.

---`<footer>`

Is this a good approach?

Thanks,

James Ford

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-section-element):

> The section element represents a generic document or application section… The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead.

So, if the main intent of the original `div`s is to help with styling/scripting, you should keep using `div`s. If it genuinely a way to separate sections of the page, use `section`s.

Comment: w3fools.com made me delete my answer as is its wont

Comment: next time... next time... this question can't be answered too many ways